# Convert folder of XYZ png tiles to TMS Tiles

Tags: tile-map-service, xyz

I have elevation/terrain tiles downloaded from https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/terrarium/{z}/{x}/{y}.png  I need to convert them to TMS Tiles.

Is there a python script that can do the re-numbering?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: An alternative to consider is to just adjust the client application, if possible. E.g. Leaflet has a `tms` option (Boolean) that allows you to declare whether the tile schema is XYZ or TMS. Otherwise it's a matter of changing the y coordinate (`y = (2^z) - y - 1`).